# China single and 3 phase

Tags: power-supply

What are the differences in number of conductors between single phase and the 3 phase used in China as compared with what is used in the U.S.A.?
It's my understanding that 220v residential is strictly a single hot and a neutral. Is their line 220v on a single leg?  I've got some Chinese equipment to wire and it appears that have 1 leg hot in their equipment while the other leg on the 220v breaker is tied to the neutral.

Comment: What does the manual say? Electrical schematics?

Comment: In the USA, 220 V, probably more properly called 240 V, is 2 hot lines and often a neutral. Each hot line is 120 V to neutral. There must also be an equipment grounding conductor that is connected to earth at the service entrance where the neutral is also connected to earth. Equipment that requires only 220 V can be connected without connecting the neutral.

Comment: Thank you but,  not helpful at all.  I know what we have in the U.S.A..  been dealing with everything from 5vdc to 480 3 phase for over 40 yrs.

Comment: All schematics are in Chinese and none of the symbols are remotely close to what we are used to.

Comment: An understanding of 220 V residential in China is of very doubtful value. If you are worried that the equipment neutral might be connected to the metal structure of the equipment, check it. If you think the neutral-connected part of the live circuit might not be good for 120 volts to ground, that is essentially a suspicion that the equipment is junk. I don't think any of us can prove or disprove that.

Answer (score 5):

China phase-to-phase voltage for 3-phase is 380V 50Hz; Phase-to-neutral is 220V. Wye (4 conductor) and delta (three conductor) are supported; for a residence it would always include a neutral.

The standard Chinese single-phase wall plug has one 220V hot and a neutral, and optionally a safety ground.

Comment: There are three common types of wall plugs in China, but all fit within your description.

Comment: The European utility companies switched to 400V phase–phase voltages 30 years ago or so.

Comment: The Q is about the wiring configuration, not the exact voltage. Yes, EU is 400Y230V, which is 'similar' to 380Y220. Reference list here: https://www.worldstandards.eu/three-phase-electric-power/

Answer (score 2):

In response to "Chinese equipment to wire":
In China blue wire goes to neutral and brown goes to line (220VAC).
The same device in the US also needs 220VAC.
In US blue goes to line 1 and brown goes to line 2. This provides the same 220VAC that the device needs. Where the problem comes in is when the device only has a single (internal) fuse. In China the fuse goes to 220VAC line voltage, so when the internal fuse blows the circuit is internally dead. In the US, both L1 and L2 are hot (relative to neutral), so when the device internal fuse blows half of the circuit is still alive. However, as the machine never sees neutral, it perceives that the power has been cut- just don't go sticking your hand into the machine when the (internal) fuse blows without first disconnecting the power at the mains service entry. 220VAC in the US will have a circuit breaker for both legs of what they call "split phase". The body of the device goes to ground. Neutral will not be connected in this case.
I know original requester is long gone, but as this question has received 3,000 views since then, I figured why not provide part of the answer.