# CHINA 220V Vs US/Canada 240v

Tags: power-supply

Im buying a 1500w Laser Machine from China and Im running into this problem. From all the forums ive read, you guys seem to make the most sense.
The machine specs is 220v +-10% 60hz as per the name plate and manual.
I have 220v single phase in my shop in Canada, which has the same system as the US.

They have 3 wires coming out of the machine:

"LIVE" wire (brown & labeled 220v)

"N" Wire (blue & labeled 0V / Null)

"G" wire (yellow/green & labeled Ground / PE)

Our 240v system:

1 Hot red wire - 120v

1 Hot black wire - 120v

1 Ground wire - ground

1 N (depending if the machine needs 120v for other electronics)

From what ive gathered, ground would be connected ground and the machines Live wire will be on our 1 hot and their N wire will be on the other hot. So 2 hots and 1 Ground.
Other US/Canada users with this machine run it this way with no problems it seems but my question would be even though it does run, is there anything that might go wrong because of the split phase/no neutral here in Us/Can? Safety wise, operation wise, yes it will work or seem to work but is there a difference that might cause an issue in the future.
PIC 1 - wires from machine
PIC 2 - Machine Schematic
PIC 3 - Our 220v system here in Canada/us
PIC 4 - Chinas 220v system

[image: wires coming out the machine]

[[image: Machine Schematic]]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGApp.jpg)

[[image: Our system here in Us/Can from my assumption]]
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DupTj.png)

[[image: Their system in China sent from their Company's Electrician]]
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8t9w.jpg)

Comment: Canada does not have 220. It is 208 or 240.

Comment: Yeah I meant 240V, the machine spec is 220v +-10%

Comment: Yes an answer from that thread was what I was looking for

Comment: What's the spec on Canadian power? 240V +/- 5%?   that could break your laser.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this answer for my question. If anyone else wants to chime in, please do, more info helps

[Answer I found](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/641592/334470)

[image: Pic]

Comment: I edited the post, is that the correct way now? Sorry Im new to this forum